# IT Security Stack Exchange Top User Swag

Tags: discussion, swag

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you have at least 1,000 reputation and are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://security.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- IT Security Stack Exchange t-shirt in your size
- IT Security Stack Exchange die-cut, vinyl stickers
- IT Security Stack Exchange key-chain flashlight
- [Stack Exchange sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies)
- [Stack Exchange pen](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens)
- [Stack Exchange stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers)

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### The t-shirt

[image: security.stackexchange.com Tshirt]

### The sticker

[image: security.stackexchange.com sticker]

### The key-chain flashlight

[image: security.stackexchange.com flashlight]

The rest of the items you can view in the [Stack Exchange store](http://shop.stackexchange.com) — direct links to [sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies), [pens](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens), [stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers).

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- the limited edition t-shirts and stickers will be available for purchase from the store as soon as we're able)</sub>

Comment: Awesomesauce! Looks great guys.

Comment: wow, don't know what to say except - thanks a lot. you rock! :)

Comment: Nice!  Thanks a lot, Rebecca & SEI guys!

Comment: I have seen these shirts. They are amazing. *Amazing*.

Comment: T-shirt looks awesome :-)

Comment: Didn't expect this one, awesome! That's how communities are built.

Comment: How did I *not* up-vote this, the first time around?  Sorry, @RebeccaChernoff.  Thanks, again!

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff - Would it be possible to get [Security.SE] polo shirts in the store, also?  I'd definitely buy some of those.

Comment: @Iszi in the future we do plan to make swag available in our store for non top users. We haven't decided if we're doing polos yet. I'll keep you posted if we do.

Comment: update from our printshop: the shirts and stickers are ready. However the flashlight won't be ready until the 2/18.

Comment: Have the emails been sent?

Comment: update 2: the swag packages have been mailed out.

Comment: Thanks for the swag!  T-shirt flashlight sticker are awesome.

Comment: i got 1 ITsec sticker, the t-shirt, the flashlight and small ITsec cards. was that what was sent in the end or should I assume that the rest of the stuff just got stolen by the border police in my case? :D not that it matters much, just curious. thanks again anyway! =)

Comment: @Jin - No swag for me... never received an email.  No worries

Comment: @makerofthings7 were you in top 2 pages at the time this post was made? we only sent emails to the top 2 page users at the date of the post.

Comment: @jin Yes, I've been there since the site started.

Comment: @makerofthings7 I'll let our community team know! you definitely should have gotten the email. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 9):

Rebecca and all at SEI: awesome!

And Jin - you were right, that design looks great on the t-shirt:)

Answer (score 6):

It looks great, but... this being a security site and all, I keep hesitating and wondering what I'll see when I press "submit" in that google form. I expect something like a list of all user details that were entered, with the message "YOU SHOULD KNOW BETTER"... :-)

Comment: TRAP, IT IS NOT.

Comment: hahahahahaha. The discussion on the DMZ was around how to protect from other hacks....

Comment: what's the DMZ?

Comment: The DMZ is the chat room for security SE: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz